# html div positioning

Tags: html, positioning

I have multiple DIVs in a php page:

```
<?php 
if ($row['a']!="") { echo "<div id=a></div>";} 
if ($row['b']!="") { echo "<div id=b></div>";}
if ($row['c']!="") { echo "<div id=c></div>";}
if ($row['d']!="") { echo "<div id=d></div>";}
if ($row['e']!="") { echo "<div id=e></div>";}
?>
```

How should i style their positioning so that if div id=2 is not displayed then the div id=3 will replace its position, so that there will not be a blank space between div 1 and 3. Same case with the rest of the DIVs. which positioning type should i use: relative? absolute?

Comment: I don't think we have the full story - what CSS are you applying? What layout are you after? If PHP doesn't echo the div, it will not be rendered and there will be no space.

Comment: @Marcopus well, there would be a space, if he used absolute or fixed positioning, cuz it doesnt care if something is rendered between then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with relative positioning. A simple example would look like below. If you can prefer class attribute for styling it would be good or else you can give a seperate styling for each div with their ID's. Go through the code below. Now try to remove the middle one or any one or two echo statements you can find that unavailable div's space gets replaced. Still there are many other ways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    .adiv {
        position:relative;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:#ff0000;
        float:left;
        margin:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo "<div id=\"one\" class=\"adiv\"> </div>";
    echo "<div id=\"two\" class=\"adiv\"> </div>";
    echo "<div id=\"three\" class=\"adiv\"> </div>";
    echo "<div id=\"four\" class=\"adiv\"> </div>";
    echo "<div id=\"five\" class=\"adiv\"> </div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```